# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES like 'value'

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm confused with an SQL query. I have a .sdf database with tables already created. I have a form that checks to see if a table exists, creates a new table, and fills it full of data from a DataGridView. I can display all of the database tables in a DataGridView using the `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` query, which works, But I only want to show certain tables ending in '_quote'. How can I 'filter' this to show all tables ending in `_quote`? (For example a table called `random_table_name_quote`).
My code so far for populating the DataGridView:

```
private void getTables()
    {            
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        string strConnect = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\LWADataBase.sdf";
        using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConnect))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", con))
            {
                using (SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter())
                {

                    da.SelectCommand = com;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "Quotation Name";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%__quote'

Comment: Works perfectly. Could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%__quote'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the sql query to filter the results!

Check the line below!

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME Like '%_quote'", con))
```

Best regards!